# Change color based on choice on dropdown and store in cookie

Tags: php, css, cookies

I have a dropdown menu with 4 different color combos. They are suppose to change background color, font and font size. I have it set up how I think it is suppose to go but when I hit submit nothing currently happens. After they hit submit the choice is suppose to save in a cookie.

```
<select name="userColorChoice">
    <option value="default"<?php if ($color =="default"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Default</option>
    <option value="highContrast"<?php if ($color =="highContrast"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>High Contrast</option>
    <option value="comboTwo"<?php if ($color =="comboTwo"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Color Combo 2</option>
    <option value="comboThree"<?php if ($color =="comboThree"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Color Combo 3</option>
    <input type="submit" name="submitColor">
</select>


//COOKIE PART
$color = "default";
if (isset($_GET['submitColor'])){
    setcookie("langCookie", "unimportant",time()-2000);
    header("Location:trivia.php");
}


if (isset($_POST['userColorChoice'])){
    $color=$_POST['userColorChoice'];
    setcookie("langCookie",$color,time()+2000000);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE['langCookie'])){
    $color = $_COOKIE['langCookie'];
} else{
    $color = "default";
}


 //switch statement to set values based on the user selection
switch ($color){
    case"default":
        echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
        echo '<body style="color:black">';
        echo '<body style="font-size:medium">';
        break;
    case "highContrast":
        echo '<body style="background-color: red">';
        echo '<body style="color:black">';
        echo '<body style="font-size:x-large">';
        break;
    case"comboTwo":
        echo '<body style="background-color:black">';
        echo '<body style="color:white">';
        echo '<body style="font-size:large">';
        break;
    case"comboThree":
        echo '<body style="background-color:red">';
        echo '<body style="color:blue">';
        echo '<body style="font-size:medium">';
        break;
    default:
        echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
        echo '<body style="color:black">';
        echo '<body style="font-size:medium">';
        break;
}
```

Comment: submit through form . set method as  post.  and not required default 2 times. and if you redirect it then it was not able to set that page body color

Comment: Just a suggestion, use CSS instead and change the StyleSheet based on the dropdown. This will allow far more to happen going forward and will be ALOT easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<select>` element can *only* contain `<option>` elements. Put the `<input>` outside it, and make sure they are both inside a `<form>`:

```
<form method=post>
    <select name="userColorChoice">
        <option value="default"<?php if ($color =="default"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Default</option>
        <option value="highContrast"<?php if ($color =="highContrast"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>High Contrast</option>
        <option value="comboTwo"<?php if ($color =="comboTwo"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Color Combo 2</option>
        <option value="comboThree"<?php if ($color =="comboThree"){ echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Color Combo 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submitColor">
</form>
```

The PHP code needs to be inside a `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First I presume the select code is actually after the rest of it?  If you have it before your body tag and before you define what $color is that would be a problem.

Next I see $_GET['submitColor'] but $_POST['userColorChoice'].  Are you using a get or a post method on your form?

Also you are using a header-redirect if the $_GET['submitColor'] is set, so any code after that is not run.